# Javascript looping through prototype

Tags: javascript

Please consider the code:

```
// define the GameObject constructor function

    var GameObject = function(width, height) {
    this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * myCanvasWidth) + 1);
    this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * myCanvasHeight) + 1);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    return this;
};

// (re)define the GameObject prototype object

GameObject.prototype = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 5,
    width: 5,
    draw: function() {
        myCanvasContext.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
};
```

We can then instantiate the GameObject 100 times.

```
var x = 100,
arrayOfGameObjects = [];
do {
    arrayOfGameObjects.push(new GameObject(10, 10));
    } while(x--);
```

Now we have an array of 100 GameObjects, which all share the same prototype and definition of the draw method, which drastically saves memory within the application.

When we call the draw method, it will reference the exact same function.

```
var GameLoop = function() {
    for(gameObject in arrayOfGameObjects) {
        gameObject.draw(); // this is my problem. Is this correct? gameObject is simply and index who draw() method gets executed
    }
};
```

My problem is with the last line code where method draw() is getting executed. Since gameObject is simply an Index, how can draw() method get executed? That index doesn't hold any object. It is simply an index right?

[Here](http://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnet.tutsplus.com%2Ftutorials%2Fjavascript-ajax%2Fprototypes-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know%2F&ei=BuVbUaCuAsz9rAeR-oGwBA&usg=AFQjCNGhA6fB7EFB1kd1ORDCBidrhIWr0A&bvm=bv.44697112,d.bmk) is a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use the following for your `GameLoop`:

```
var GameLoop = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfGameObjects.length; i++) {
        arrayOfGameObjects[i].draw();
    }
};
```

Comment: ya u are right but since im having a problem with that i need a help on that special case

Comment: see my last line code where draw() method gets executed ,is that correct since var gameObject only holds index no object how draw method gets executed?

Comment: No. In your particular instance your LOC should be: `arrayOfGameObjects[gameObject].draw()`.

Comment: i have placed a link plz see it

Comment: I still don't understands your problem. My comment above tells you how it should be...

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain `for` loop to iterate through an array.

```
var GameLoop = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfGameObjects.length; i++) {
        arrayOfGameObjects[i].draw();
    }
};
```

It's actually bad practice to use a `for in` loop on an array since it's just a round about way to get the indexes that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I like jquery **$.each**

```
$.each(arrayOfGameObjects, function(i, gObject) {
    gObject.draw();
});
```

Otherwise as described by others use **for** with iteration using array length.

Answer (score 0):

```
var GameLoop = function() {
    for(var i = 0, len = arrayOfGameObjects.length; i<len; i++) {
        gameObject.draw();
    }
};
```

See this working on http://jsfiddle.net/SdBcx/2/

Some notes:

- It is bad practice to use the `for(obj in array)` on Array objects. The reason why is, if you add a custom function to `Array.prototype`, the custom function will appear in your for loop! I've written an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/BUp6T/
- You can see that I am saving the `arrayOfGameObjects.length` in the `len` variable. This happens only once, before the loop executes. This is significantly faster than the common solution which is: `for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfGameObjects.length; i++)` which retrieves the array length every single loop iteration.